# Why does my addClass not work?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have the below line of code that doesn't work:

```
$( "ul li.open > a" ).addClass( "level-one" );
```

Yet if I change it to find the ID rather than the class it works

I need to get this to work without targeting an ID:

```
$( "ul li#menu-item-24 > a" ).addClass( "level-one" );
```

Here's the code dev tools gives me (this is with the ID line of code above), am I being stupid here?:

[image: Screenshot]:

I'm trying to target the link that goes to Google (used for an example).

Its worth noting dev tools doesn't bring any errors back for either line.

**EDIT**

OK the `.open` class is added when a first level link is clicked (the structure is for an accordion menu plugin I'm using - https://github.com/tefra/navgoco) and as requested here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="demo1" class="nav"><li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-24 open"><a href="http://google.com">Logged In<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" data-index="0" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25"><a href="#test" class="boobies">Sub menu item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-26"><a href="http://skills.com">Testing<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" data-index="1" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27"><a href="http://boom.com" class="boobies">Child</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The JS for the plugin can be found here: https://github.com/tefra/navgoco/blob/master/src/jquery.navgoco.js

All I'm doing to it is initialising the accordion like this:

```
$("#demo1").navgoco({accordion: true});
```

Comment: What doesn't work about your code?

Comment: @tymeJV I need to put the level-one classname on that Google link but not using a specific ID

Comment: Try using this: `$('li.open').children('a').addClass('level-one');`

Comment: We need a bit more code as what you wrote can work perfectly with the right html structure. Can you provide detailed HTML? The class ```open``` might be added by some jQuery action and so not detected at first.

Comment: @thomasstephn That's correct it its added when a button is clicked on an accordion. I was just about to update my question with that nugget of info

Comment: That might be your issue. Waiting for your detailed code to help you more on that one

Comment: Are you refering jquery library? Added $(document).ready(function(){}); ? I need more information to help you

Comment: Can you show the JS you're using to add the open class?

Comment: @Brandon I've updated the question but because its a plugin I have linked directly to their file on GitHub : https://github.com/tefra/navgoco/blob/master/src/jquery.navgoco.js

Comment: The issue isn't targeting, the structure you have should work fine. The issue is jQuery can't find the .open class because it was injected after the DOM loaded.

Comment: @Brandon So how do I get it to work?

Comment: Does nkmol or thomasstephn solution below work?

Comment: @Brandon No they didn't

Comment: @egr103 any luck with my suggestion below?

Comment: I have fixed it myself and posted the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19844195/1160619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had a dig through the plugin I'm using and found the way that it targets that particular link:

```
$( "li:has(ul) > a" ).addClass( "level-one" );
```

This worked. I do appreciate the amount of people that made an effort to try to and help.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using the `>` operator, as I always fail using it. I would do this:

```
$("ul li.open a").first().addClass("level-one");
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work when targeting the classname, which is what I need to do. FYI it worked using the ID I don't get it.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( "ul li.open a:first" ).addClass( "level-one" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class is added after, it might needed to be written like so:

```
$("ul").find(".open > a").addClass("level-one");
```

Comment: Bummer. Do you have your entire html, js and CSS? Can you put them here so we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your ul is loaded with the .nav class by default and it's not added in later.

```
$('ul.nav').on('click','.menu-item', function(){
    $(this).children('a').first().addClass('level-one');
});
```